# getting this error in R when printing the clusters in terms of the Food labels

Tags: r

```
food.2.clust <- lapply(1:2, function(nc) check_food_clustering[cut.2==nc])
```

Show Traceback

Rerun with Debug
 Error in `[.data.frame(check_food_clustering, cut.2 == nc)` as

> undefined columns selected

Comment: Food Energy Protein Fat Calcium Iron

Comment: > hc.complete=hclust(dist(check_food_clustering), method="complete")
> cut.2 <- cutree(hc.complete.link, k=2)
> food.2.clust <- lapply(1:2, function(nc) check_food_clustering[cut.2==nc])
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in `[.data.frame`(check_food_clustering, cut.2 == nc) : 
  undefined columns selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`food.2.clust <- lapply(1:2, function(nc) check_food_clustering[cut.2==nc, ])`

You need a comma after the condition `cut.2==nc`